# Looking for an idiom for expressing difficulties at an early stage of a process

Tags: idioms

In Hebrew there's an expression to describe this - "Labor Pains"
It expresses the difficulties experienced in the very first stages of a long process.
For example, the difficulties experienced at the beginning of every new relationship that later will be bridged once one get to know each other.
I am looking for a similar idiom in English.
Please note, "burning pancakes" and "first crepe always comes out wrong" is not appropriate here. These rather describe the difficulties in the first tries of a repetitive process.

Thanks!

Comment: [Teething troubles](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/teething%20troubles%2Fproblems#:~:text=Definition%20of%20teething%20troubles%2Fproblems,-British&text=%3A%20small%20problems%20that%20happen%20when,when%20we%20began%20our%20business.) maybe?

Comment: Sounds like [*paying your dues*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pay-your-dues) or paying tuition at [*the school of hard knocks*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=school%20of%20hard%20knocks). Similarly, [*Rebbe Gelt*](https://atlantajewishtimes.timesofisrael.com/rebbe-gelt/).

Comment: There are many alternatives for this context. Literal and metaphoric [***growing pains***](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/growing-pains/symptoms-causes/syc-20354349#:~:text=Growing%20pains%20are%20often%20described,no%20evidence%20that%20growth%20hurts.) is one that comes to mind.

Comment: I've actually heard "labor pains" used to describe a difficult roll-out of a new process.

Comment: Thank you all! very helpful